# Changing output structure of MySQL query without using PHP

Tags: mysql, database

I am currently querying a MySQL database for data and getting results back in PHP.

I am running the query

```
SELECT title.id, title.title, title.description
FROM co_titles title
WHERE title.id = :title
```

And I am getting the result back as follows:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1966 
        [title] => Example Title 
        [description] => Example Description
    )
)
```

There is nothing wrong with the query and this is the exact result I expect, however I would like my result to look like this:

```
Array (
    [1966] => Array (
        [title] => Example Title 
        [description] => Example Description
    )
)
```

**SEE EDIT BELOW, this is no longer relevant:** Is there a way I can modify my query in order to make the output look like this? I want to do this without using PHP, only MySQL, unless this is completely impossible in MySQL!

I thank you all very much for your help, I have been banging my head against a wall on this one.

**EDIT:** Okay it seems that basically what I was trying to do was impossible. Could someone assist with the most efficient way of converting from one to the other?

Okay I figured it out, for anyone after me, the best way I found was as follows:

```
function parseNotes($notes)
{
    $returnarray = array();
    foreach($notes as $i)
    {
        $returnarray[$i['id']] = $i;
        unset($returnarray[$i['id']]['id']);
    }
    return $returnarray;
}
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The records returned by the query is linear. The only way to do that is by formating it in your PHP code. `MySQL`  is a server a has no capability to do that even if you use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using PHP code, I have added my code above to help anyone else out who may be searching for this later as well.

Answer (score 0):

The is no way to achieve this straight out of MySQL. The only way to achieve this would be to map your results array to another array using the id from your results array as the index for your new array.